# Is there a method to standardise form content in MVC razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, partial-views

I have a standardised form layout like this:

```
<div class="ContentSection">

    <div class="ContentSection__content">

        <form class="Form form" method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="Form__editors">

                @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Id)

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Publishing
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PublishOptionsEditor)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Content
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Slug)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OneLiner)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.HtmlContent)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustomMetaTitle)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustomMetaDescription)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Primary Image
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PrimaryImageEditor)
                    </div>
                </div>

                @Html.Partial("_FormControls", "Save")
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

...where the only bit that changes is this, in the middle:

```
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Slug)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OneLiner)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.HtmlContent)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustomMetaTitle)
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustomMetaDescription)
```

Is there a recommended way to standardise the surrounding layout for different models?

- I don't think I can use a `@helper` because of the model typing and `@Html.EditorFor` content.
- `@RenderSection` can only be called in the master layout and I don't want to create a new master view just for this.
- The ViewModels all implement an interface, that I can use with `PartialViews`, but I'd like to make use of the `DataAnnotations` that I have on each specific ViewModel and I don't know how to do this.

I feel there may be an obvious way to do this that I am overlooking.